# d3js force layout sorting and position issue

Tags: d3.js

I have created following visualisation with a force layout but I have two more problems to solve.

[image]

I'd like to have every angle the same size. As you can see, the space between 'Duitsland' and 'Nederland' is larger than 'Nederland' and 'Italië'. I have a feeling it won't be possible because every node is a 'magnet' and we don't have much control over it.

Second problem is sorting the position of the nodes according to the edge weight. Again, also a problem that can't be solved in a force layout?

Comment: Probably can't be solved via forcelayout but you could set the node positions explicitly

Comment: Like what @thisOneGuy said, if you don't use force layout this would be very easy to do. If you try to set positions explicit with force layout they'll simply be reset when you resume the physics. I have done this before, but I presented them as essentially "presentation layouts" which aren't interactive in terms of physics. If you absolutely need force layout **and** this, perhaps you could set the layout and then resume physics on click/mouse event.